# bash script prepending ? to file name

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am using the below script. When I have it echo `$f` as shown below, it gives the correct result:

```
#/bin/bash
var="\/home\/"

while read p; do
    f=$(echo $p | sed "s/${var}/\\n/g")
    f=${f%.sliced.bam}.fastq
    echo $f
    ~/bin/samtools view $p | awk '{print "@"$1"\n"$10"\n+\n"$11}' > $f
    ./run.sh $f ${f%.fastq}
    rm ${f%.sliced.bam}.fastq
done < $1
```

I get the output as expected

```
test.fastq
```

But the file being created by `awk > $f` has the name

```
?test.fastq
```

Note that the overall goal here is to run this loop on every file listed in a file with absolute paths but then write locally (which is what the sed call is for)

edit: Run directly on the command line (without variables) the `samtools | awk` line runs correctly.

Comment: Why are you doing `"\n+\n"` in awk?

Comment: The fastq file format has a + spacer line. The awk command on its own produces a proper fastq file.

Comment: Try changing echo to: `echo -e "$f"`

Comment: That seems to show a prepended newline, the command now goes `$ sh test.sh name
(newline)
test.fastq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk cannot possibly have anything to do with your problem. The shell is completely responsible for file redirection, so f MUST have a weird character in it.

Most likely whatever you are sending to this script has a special character in it (e.g. perhaps a UTF character, and your terminal is showing ASCII only). When you do the echo, the shell doesn't know how to display the char, and probably just shows it as whitespace, and when you send it through ls (which might be doing things like colorization) it combines in a strange way and ends up showing the ?.

Oh wait...why are you putting a newline into the filename with sed??? That is possibly your problem...try just:

```
sed "s/${var}//g"
```

Comment: I am using a newline because I copied that code from another stackoverflow post without understanding it. I believe that fixed the problem.

Comment: Yeah...the shell is perfectly happy to embed special characters (including newlines) into filenames. Back in the old days you would often the get backspace key screwed up, embed backspaces in a file (e.g. my^?^?thefile) and ls would display it as thefile (obeying the ^? as a backspace)...but the filename really was 'm y CTRL-? CTRL-? t h e f i l e'